# Yii 1.1 TbGridView with search Condition do not apply

Tags: gridview, yii, conditional-statements

**The Code in de View where the Grid is build:**

*gleicherKunde is German for: "sameCustomer"*

```
 <?php
    $model = new Person("search");
    $model->gleicherKunde = 1;

    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
        'id'=>'person-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'columns'=>array(
            'id',


            'vorname',
            'nachname',
            'funktion',
            /*'durchwahl',*/
            'telefonMobile',
            array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
    ));
}

?>
```

**And in the model where i set the Condition for only Persons with same Kunde(Customer)**

```
if($this->gleicherKunde) {

    $kunde = Kunde::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>'t.kunde'));
    if (isset($kunde)) {
        $criteria->AddCondition('t.kunde = "'.$kunde->id.'"' );
    }
}
```

The problem is, i get everytime all persons and not only the person where id is t.kunde.

If i replace t.kunde with an ID per example 145, i am getting only the costumers with id 145.

Where is my thinking error?

Answer (score 0):

i found a Solution in replace the Dataprovider from this:

```
$model = new Dial("search"); 

$model->nichtZugeordnet = true;

'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
```

to

```
 $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Person', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'kunde= '.$model->id,
```